# How Kafka broker works even zookeeper cluster down

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have configured three zookeeper nodes cluster, with two broker's connecting to zookeeper cluster.

I have created topic , to do test cases fail-over or loss while sending messages.

Based on consumer group example, I have  ran two consumer shell's to consume messages

I have sent an an text file data like line by line ..produce the messages.

at final test case i  **have shutdown the all zookeeper nodes and one broker**.

still I could able to produce and consume total messages with only one broker. How its possible ?

Here is my Architecture[Kafka Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eodHJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

This [article](https://data-flair.training/blogs/zookeeper-in-kafka/) explains the role of zookeeper in Kafka.

To answer your question. client would work until the next refresh of metadata happens. Client gets the metadata of topics it connects if not available like partitions and their leaders. Now once it has these then it directly connects with those brokers and produces/consumes messages unless leaders change and also until next refresh of metadata happens. Metadata refresh is periodical operation.

#### metadata.max.age.ms

> The period of time in milliseconds after which we force a refresh of metadata even if we haven't seen any partition leadership changes to proactively discover any new brokers or partitions.